# Duplicated values in listview fetched from database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have an incoming call history app. Every time I call it takes the number and save it in the database, after that it adds it to the list which in turn added to the listview. But I have one problem which is it never checks for old values and it adds duplicated numbers to the database, is there any way to avoid this? Here is my try.

```
public class Incoming_call_history extends Activity {

private ListView lv;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String>list;
DataSourceCall DS;
boolean duplicated=false;
String temp="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_call_history);
    DS= new DataSourceCall(this);
    DS.open();
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.callHistory);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);

    list=(ArrayList<String>) DS.getAllCalls();

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    int number = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int date = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int type = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);


    while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {


        String num = mCursor.getString(number);
        String dur = mCursor.getString(duration);
        String datee = mCursor.getString(date);
        String calltype = mCursor.getString(type);
        Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf(datee));
        String callTypeStr = "";
        switch (Integer.parseInt(calltype)) {
        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            callTypeStr = "Missed";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            callTypeStr = "Outgoing";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            callTypeStr = "Incoming";
            break;

        }

            boolean found = false;
        for (int ndx = 0; ndx < list.size(); ndx++)
        {
            if (num.equals(list.contains(num)))
                    {
                found = true;
                DS.deleteCall(num);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
                    }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            DS.createCall(num);
            temp=num;
            Log.d("added succesfuly ", num);

        } 

        //  list.add("Phone number: "+num+"\n"+"Duration: " + dur+"\n"+"Type: " + callTypeStr+"\n"+"Call date: " + d+"\n");

    }
    mCursor.close();

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}}
```

Comment: what you can do is before setting your list to adapter you can check for the duplicates in the list and eliminate them and then set the list to adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to insert already inserted mobile number in the table,Just check whether the mobile number is already inserted not

```
public int isUserAvailable(int number)
{
    int numberCount = 0;
    Cursor c = null;
    try
    {
        c = db.rawQuery("select p_number from user_table where p_number = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(number)});

        if(c.getCount() != 0)
            numberCount = c.getCount();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(c!=null) c.close();
    }
    return numberCount ;
}
```

If it does not suits with your requirement let me know,I will try to give some other solution.

Comment: Where is the the other method rawQuery?